# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в предложениях или нужно заменить на другие?

Tags: пунктуация, авторская-пунктуация

1) Ведь если ты умрёшь - умрёт та, кто пожертвовала всем, чтобы мы добрались в город. 
2) Величина стены поразила юношу - это было видно по его глазам. 
3) Установив всё обратно, парень попытался завести машину ещё раз - и машина завелась. 
Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в предложениях или нужно заменить на другие?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) ***Ведь если ты умрёшь — умрёт та, кто пожертвовала всем, чтобы мы добрались в город.***

Постановка тире **допустима**, что связано с **пропуском** второй части двойного союза ЕСЛИ...ТО. В то же время это предложение лучше исправить, если правка возможна.

*Ведь если ты умрёшь, то умрёт та, которая пожертвовала всем, чтобы мы добрались в город.*

Тире при обозначении союзной подчинительной связи является дополнительным знаком, оно чаще применяется в СПП с одним придаточным (а не в сложных конструкциях), когда можно чётко обозначить условные отношения.

Сочетание ***та, кто***  для лиц женского рода проблематично, там есть ограничения. http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_05

2) ***Величина стены поразила юношу — это было видно по его глазам.***

Розенталь:

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151

9. Если вторая часть бессоюзного сложного предложения представляет собой присоединительное предложение, перед ней ставится **тире** (возможно вставить слово ***это***, которое иногда имеется в самом предложении): Они расстанутся, они уже расстались — эта мысль ошеломила обоих (Гран.)

3) ***Установив всё обратно, парень попытался завести машину ещё раз - и машина завелась.***

Розенталь  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135#pp135

Тире ставится: 1. Если во второй части сложносочиненного предложения содержится **неожиданное присоединение** или резкое противопоставление, то между частями перед сочинительным союзом вместо запятой ставится тире: Вавила бросил что-то в костёр, притоптал — и тотчас же стало очень темно (Ч.).

Comment: Sharon, спасибо вам огромное! Да, в предложениях правка возможна. Я исправила первое предложение, как вы указали: Ведь если ты умрёшь, то умрёт та, которая пожертвовала всем, чтобы мы добрались в город. Рада, что второе предложение оказалось правильным.  Хоть что-то... А в третьем предложении  тогда я заменю тире на  запятую. Дай Бог вам здоровья!